# Old movie with 2 girls which mistakenly break an egg, which surprisingly contained a diamond

Tags: story-identification, movie

I am interested to understand what movie I saw when I was in kinder-garden. Occasionally, a guy came (organized by the teacher) and projected films on the wall. I have a clear memory about only one - at least, a memory which can lead to a movie identification.

I saw that movie in 1980-1982 or around that time, so the movie is definitely older.

The scene is like this:

- there were two girls, one older, one younger; the age difference was visible, at least a few years;
- the older girl seemed to be in charge of the younger, and the younger trusted the older; they might have been sisters;
- they had an egg - if I remember correctly, the younger girl was holding it in her hands;
- they were in something which I considered to be a cave; maybe a tunnel, but the walls were still soil or stone, not like the road or railway tunnels of today;
- they were hungry (probably that's what we were told by the adults in the room, the teacher and the projector guy; we as children were not able to read subtitles and understand);
- by mistake, the younger girl drops the egg and the egg breaks;
- they were both sorry for the unfortunate event and regretted it;
- the surprise came when from the egg fell a big diamond (or other valuable stone) instead of the typical yellow and white content;
- the movie was color, not black-and-white;

For the following, I no longer have an image in mind, but I think I still keep the knowledge:

- if I remember correctly, they were chased by some men, inside those caves;
- the men might have been carrying swords; maybe Aladdin Arabian swords;
- when the egg scene happened, the girls were trying to hide;
- the events might have happened somewhere in the Orient; I think I know that they wore clothes typical to the characters in the story of Aladdin;

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something, but can you elaborate on the fantasy/science fiction content? And do you remember what language the film was in, since you mention subtitles and that the adults had to translate?

Comment: I have to assume that it was fantasy / fairy tale / folks tale considering that diamonds are not often found in usual eggs. And it is my general feeling that it was fantasy. Surely not science. Regarding the language of the movie, your guess is as good as mine. BTW, my native tongue is not English, so the language could have been English.

Comment: ^_^ FWIW, found while searching for this: https://www.huffpost.com/entry/sally-thompson-egg-in-diamond_n_58d14a2ce4b00705db52ef63

Just for the sake of eliminating potential matches, what is your native language?

Comment: Wow!  Maybe I will start eating eggs again :)) In "my" movie, the diamond is big, pretty much the size of the egg. I guesstimate that it was a chicken egg.